# Want to use 2 external monitors along with laptop screen

Tags: windows-10, usb, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I would like to have 2 external HDMI monitors along with my Dell laptop screen.

Here is what I plan to do after doing a bit search

The laptop has dedicated HDMI port and USB-C

- First HDMI monitor directly connected to the HDMI port
- Use a Dell Adaptor(USB Type C to HDMI) to connect to the USB-C port of the laptop, then from the HDMI out of the Adaptor, connect to the second HDMI monitor.

and of course, the primary screen will be my laptop screen.

With the above setup, does it can be used for the 'Extend' option on the Windows operating system for all the 3 monitors?.

Comment: In order to help you it would be useful to know the model of your laptop

Comment: @spike_66 dell inspiron 7570

Comment: According to the [notebookcheck.net](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-Inspiron-15-7570-i7-8550U-940MX-Laptop-Review.263654.0.html) review, the USB-C port supports a DisplayPort connection. So a monitor with this type of connection can take advantage of this port without having to use an adapter

Comment: @spike_66 I meant a Dell USB-C Adapter like this https://www.amazon.in/Dell-USB-C-Mobile-Adapter-DA300/dp/B079MDQDP4
https://www.amazon.in/Dell-1960034-Da200-USB-C-Multi-Adapter/dp/B012DT6KW2